# How can I get a JS string to go into the "type" attribute of my "input" tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code:

```
<input id="elective" type="variable" placeholder="whats your elective" name="user text" >
```

How can I get a string to go into the `type` attribute in the `input` tag?

Comment: I have no clue what you are actually trying to do. What are you setting the type to dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `getAttribute` once you select the DOM node.

```js
const type = document.querySelector('#elective').getAttribute('type');

console.log(type);
```

```html
<input id="elective" type="variable" placeholder="whats your elective" name="user text" />
```